# jQuery selector table query

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have following html

```
<table>
    <th>Name</th><th>age</th>
    <tbody>
        <tr><td>A</td><td>25</td></tr>
        <tr><td>B</td><td>30</td></tr>
        <tr><td>C</td><td>34</td></tr>
        <tr><td>D</td><td>32</td></tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I want to select all tr inside tbody. Hence I used:

```
$('table tbody tr').css('background-color','yellow');
```

Highlight all TRs inside TBODY inside Table with yellow.
This shouldn't select TH row, but it strangely does and highlights it yellow. Any thoughts!
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your markup isn't 100% valid so the browser is fixing it for you. See [the spec](http://dev.w3.org/html5/markup/table.html) for the allowed `<table>` structure.

Wrap the `<th>` elements in a `<thead>`.

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <th>Name</th><th>age</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr><td>A</td><td>25</td></tr>
        <tr><td>B</td><td>30</td></tr>
        <tr><td>C</td><td>34</td></tr>
        <tr><td>D</td><td>32</td></tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: One need to wait for 10 minutes after posting a question before reply can be marked as answer. Hence couldn't do that instantly. Done now! thanks again.